# Issue with wildcard after one letter + asterisk

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, kql

I'm trying to investigate what's wrong with my KQL queries and it looks like a bug.

For example when I query:

[image]

It causes error, but for following queries it is ok:

[image]
[image]

How to understand that?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by replacing spaces to '+' in query