# SharePoint Search Issue: Wildcard after one letter throws error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, 2019, query, kql

#### Summary:

On an SP2019 environment, "test a*" search query throws an Unknown error while "test t*" query works just fine. Tested from both SP default search page and from Search Query tool.
[image]
`HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException","message":{"lang":"de-DE","value":"Unbekannter Fehler."}}} (EN: "Unknown error")`

[image]

#### Details:

Several queries that do not work: "test a*", "test b*", "test c*" (and other letters like: d, e, f, h) + (one digit followed by asterisk): "test 1*" ... "test 9*"

Several queries that work: "test g*", "test t*", "test 12*" (all other letter from the alphabet except the ones mentioned above.)  - "test" can be replaced with anyting, same results.

This issue happens on dev, test and prod environments where our solution is installed. Also worth mentioning that on other dev environments with SP2019 installed, this issue does not reproduce.

#### Investigation

Error from the logs:

```
Exception occured in scope Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchService.query. Exception=Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException: Unbekannter Fehler. ---> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.InternalQueryErrorException: Problem bei der Suche, das die Rückgabe von Ergebnissen verhindert. Wenn das Problem weiterhin besteht, wenden Sie sich an den Administrator. (EN: "Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned. If the issue persists, please contact your administrator")   
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.IssueImsDirectQuery(QueryProperties properties, _ImsQueryInternalType imsService, ConstellationLoadBalancer loadBalancer, Stopwatch sw, Action`1 postProcessResultTable, Action`1 logSuccess, Action`1 logFailure, Boolean echoEnabled)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.ExecuteInternal(QueryProperties properties, SearchServiceLogEvent logEvent)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query, SearchExecutorLogEvent evt)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query, SearchExecutorLogEvent evt)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query, SearchExecutorLogEvent evt)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query, SearchExecutorLogEvent evt)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission[T](Func`1 f)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery_Client(Query query)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery_Client(Query query)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchService.<ExecuteQuery>b__e(KeywordQuery query)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchService.Execute[T](Action`1 initializer, Func`2 executor)     -
```

Possible reason:  `[class fs::wildcard_cutoff_exception]expansion of wildcard will possibly exceed 10000 terms:`
while checking for a correlation error, found the following error. Could it be that SharePoint can't handle so many word possibilities?
[image]

```
Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.Search.QueryService.IndexNodeQueryService: Pushing error to client.: Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.FastServerException: IndexComponent1-f87c9954-56ca-41ec-aac0-d16b871df9f0-SPa8d38fd1734a.I.0.0: [class fs::wildcard_cutoff_exception]expansion of wildcard will possibly exceed 10000 terms: [lookup, correlation id: A2D933A0-9078-A06F-DE2D-ED675730FE94] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x6d6de C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0xb38b3b C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x2b25ef C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0xa830c2 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0xa7a1aa C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x3f3156 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x40c3d4 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x3f3d3f C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x55e643 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x562c98 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x564f7d C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CONCRT140.dll + 0x28198 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x55e908 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x561b27 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Search\Native\Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Native.dll + 0x564251 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CONCRT140.dll + 0x9c67 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CONCRT140.dll + 0x124d8 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CONCRT140.dll + 0x12415 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CONCRT140.dll + 0x11a73 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CONCRT140.dll + 0x28fde C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.dll + 0x17974 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll + 0x5a2d1     
 at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.FastServer.Plugin.Lookup(Byte[] queryBuffer, Int64 generationId, Byte[]& resultBuffer, Byte[]& refineBuffer, Int64 maxNumHitsToReturn, Int64 offsetInResultSet, Boolean enableRankLog, String ranking_model, String aggrspec, String sortspec, String defaultIndex, Boolean skiplistEnabled, Boolean precalcEnabled, TimeSpan timeout, Dictionary`2 perQueryFlights, String docACLs, Boolean expectSecurityTrimming, Byte[] filterQueryBuffer, String dynamicContextLists)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.Indexes.FastServerIndex.QueryLookup.Lookup(ExecuteQueryParameters parameters, Byte[]& aggregationBlob, String& queryMode)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.Search.QueryService.IndexNodeQueryService.ExecuteQuery(ExecuteQueryRequest`1 request)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.Search.QueryService.IndexNodeQueryService.ProcessExecuteQuery(ExecuteQueryRequest`1 request)
```

Could it be a SP Search configuration issue? If so, where should I start looking?

#### Related issues / topics that I've tried

[Issue with wildcard after one letter + asterisk](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/253333/issue-with-wildcard-after-one-letter-asterisk)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search-limits

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/search/search-errors-windows-server-2019

Comment: Then have you tried `+` in your query? Check my answer, if it's work for you.

Comment: unfortunately, the workaround doesn't work in my case.  I still get the same issue for the following query: "test+a*" 
same in the browser: <siteUrl>/_api/search/query?querytext=%27"test+a*"%27

Answer (score 0):

An easier option would be to restart related app pool, service on all SharePoint servers.

Resolution:

Follow the below steps to resolve this issue. If problem still persists, you may need to follow up with your Administrator.

1. From IIS - Restart (Stop-Start) the application pool for
   SecurityTokenService on all SharePoint FARM servers.
2. From Central Admin - Restart (Stop-Start) the Search Query and Site Settings Service on all SharePoint FARM servers hosting query component.
3. Perform an IISRESET on all SharePoint servers in FARM.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I followed all the steps, but the issue still occurs.